# Trying to call function<T> where T: TheClass, new() within where T: class

Tags: c#, generics

This is a simplified version of what I need to do. In its current state, what I am trying to do doesn't make sense. However it shows the problem in a simple way.

I need to call a **function2<T>() where T: TheClass, new()** within a **function1<T>() where T: class**

```
Something<T> function1<T>() where T : class {
  //cannot call function2 directly due to compile error
  //return function2<T>();

  //What I need as a pseudo code
  if (T is TheClass and T is new())
    return Then function2<T>()
  else
    throw Exception
} 

Something<T> function2<T>() where T : TheClass, new() {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Since you throw exception anyway if input is not valid - why not apply the same restrictions (TheClass, new()) to function1?

Comment: what compiler error are you getting trying to call function2 directly and for what type T?

Comment: @MarcoFatica It doesn't matter what `T` is   Since the constraint on `function1` doesn't force it to have a default constructor it can't be used at the parameter for `function2`.

Comment: Since you want different logic based on what `T` is you're going to have to resort to reflection, or use one method for new-able types and another method for other types.

Answer (score 2):

`new()` restriction can't be verified at run-time (unlike inheritance where you can use `as`/`is`) - so there is no C# construct you can write to invoke `function2` from `function1` and keep it strongly typed.

Your only option is to construct method via reflection and than call it. See [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Answer (score 0):

You really cannot do that. I'm guessing that `function2` is at some point doing `new T()`, and this might just not be possible for `T : class` constrained in `function1`.

You might try for example removing the `new()` constraint and doing it manually using checks against `ConstructorInfo`, and get an instance from it as well:

```
   Type type = typeof(T);
   ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
   if(ctor == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
   object instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[0]);
```